# Converting datetime to date in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate, janitor

I'm having difficult converting datetime data to a date cell in R. Data are from this data collection on http://data-ral.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/raleigh-police-incidents-srs/data.

The website lists the first "incident date" as "29/04/2005, 3:36 am". However, when I download the data and import it to R, it comes out as "1.114710e+12"; I've reproduced the first six cells below.

```
   INC_DATETIME
          <dbl>
1 1114709760000
2 1104581100000
3 1105283580000
4 1105748940000
5 1107976740000
6 1113182880000
```

This is impervious the reliable function from the janitor package, `excel_numeric_to_date()`. Any clue as to what I need to do to convert these to date?

Comment: Would you mind to share data in an appropriate way, e.g. using `dput`. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: I've given it a go and updated the post. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a numeric in milliseconds from the unix-epoch (1970-01-01)... so first divide by 1000, en then make is a posix. Make sure to set the correct timezone!

For me (Netherlands), the data is presented in timezone "Europe/Amsterdam"... but this might differ for you...

```
as.POSIXct( 1114709760000/1000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam" )

[1] "2005-04-28 19:36:00 CEST"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data_tbl <- read.csv("Raleigh_Police_Incidents_(SRS).csv")
data_tbl$INC_DATETIME1 <- as.POSIXct(data_tbl$INC_DATETIME/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
data_tbl$date_format <- as.Date(data_tbl$INC_DATETIME1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
data_tbl <- data_tbl %>%  
    mutate(only_date = ymd(date_format), date = day(only_date))
head(data_tbl$date)
```

***`# [1] 28  1  9 15  9 11`***

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df <- read.csv("./Data/Raleigh_Police_Incidents_(SRS).csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$INC_DATETIME1 <- as.POSIXct(df$INC_DATETIME/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
```